# Redisson JAR execution: ClassNotFoundException: org.redisson.RedissonReference

Tags: java, maven, redis, redisson

Spring Boot v2.1.2 on Java 11 not working when being executed via compiled Jar file complaining on missing class 
 (***ClassNotFoundException: org.redisson.RedissonReference***).
Although everything works when running code directly via Intellij.

See below maven ***pom.xml*** and ***stacktrace*** that I get when running compiled jar:

```
'13-02-2020 21:14:56.905 [redisson-netty-2-18] WARN  i.n.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.onUnhandledInboundException - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
...skipping...
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1432)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1199)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1243)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:648)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:583)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: class not found CLASSNAME:org.redisson.RedissonReference loader:jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@8bcc55f
        at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTObjectInput.readObject(FSTObjectInput.java:247)
        at org.redisson.codec.FstCodec$1.decode(FstCodec.java:250)
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:368)
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decodeCommand(CommandDecoder.java:196)
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:134)
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:104)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:366)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: class not found CLASSNAME:org.redisson.RedissonReference loader:jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@8bcc55f
        at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzNameRegistry.classForName(FSTClazzNameRegistry.java:235)
        at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzNameRegistry.classForName(FSTClazzNameRegistry.java:190)
        at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzNameRegistry.decodeClass(FSTClazzNameRegistry.java:173)
        at org.nustaq.serialization.coders.FSTStreamDecoder.readClass(FSTStreamDecoder.java:478)
        at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTObjectInput.readClass(FSTObjectInput.java:939)
        at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTObjectInput.readObjectWithHeader(FSTObjectInput.java:347)
        at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTObjectInput.readObjectInternal(FSTObjectInput.java:331)
        at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTObjectInput.readObject(FSTObjectInput.java:311)
        at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTObjectInput.readObject(FSTObjectInput.java:245)
        ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.redisson.RedissonReference
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzNameRegistry.classForName(FSTClazzNameRegistry.java:197)
        ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Maven *pom.xml*

```
...
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>11</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
...


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-retry.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>${common-csv.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-ri</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>${jaxb-ri.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>${httpcore.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.redisson/redisson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.all.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
        <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
        <version>${podam.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Will be happy to receive directions on what is wrong.

Comment: Show Dependency Settings

Comment: @yeahseol added also the pom dependencies section